# SQL Before Delete IF statement

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

Ok so I'm writing a trigger in sql and what needs to happen is that if t is deleted and f.actDepartDateTime is not null then the table is backed up and then deleted but I can't seem to get it to work?

```
CREATE TABLE BACKUP_table (
      f_id         number,
      t_number      number,
      s_number number
);



CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t_delete
    BEFORE DELETE ON t IF f.actDepartDateTime Not Null
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

   -- insert a row into the backup table  

   INSERT INTO BACKUP_Table (f_id, t_number, s_number)
   VALUES(old.fid, old.tnum, old.sNum);
END;
```

Comment: tag with database platform.  What does "not work" mean?  Where is table T? what is F?

Comment: The trigger doesn't backup if the ticket t table is deleted, doesn't seem to matter if f.actdepartTime is null or not null, just does nothing. Sorry is Oracle apex sql

Comment: Presumably, you are getting a syntax error when you try to create the trigger.  In the future, it would be really helpful to include those errors as well as the definition of the table the trigger is defined on so we can reproduce the issue.  I think I identified all the syntax errors but I had to guess a bit at how `t` is defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If you want a trigger to fire conditionally, the keyword is `when` not `if`.
- The syntax for doing a `null` comparison is `is null` or `is not null`.
- In the trigger body, you need to prefix references to the `:old` pseudo-record with a colon

I am not sure what `f.actDepartureDateTime` is supposed to reference-- there is no `f` alias anywhere in the code you posted.  I'm guessing that `actDepartureDateTime` is a column in the table `t` and that you want to fire the trigger based on the `old` value of that column.

Assuming that is what you are looking for, this should work

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t_delete
    BEFORE DELETE ON t 
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN( old.actDepartDateTime IS Not Null )
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO BACKUP_Table (f_id, t_number, s_number)
    VALUES(:old.fid, :old.tnum, :old.sNum);
END;
```